# Центрирование картинки на canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Имеется такой код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Canvas from scratch</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
      function getRandomInt() {
              return Math.floor(Math.random() * (255 - 0)) + 0;
            }
         $(document).ready(function() {
       var coin = new Image();
                coin.src = 'coin.png';
                var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var coordinates = 70*i;
                    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb("+getRandomInt()+", "+getRandomInt()+", "+getRandomInt()+")";  
                    ctx.fillRect(coordinates, 0, 70, 70);  
     ctx.font = "bold 30px Verdana,sans-serif";
     ctx.lineWidth = 1;
     ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                    ctx.strokeText("Н", 70*(i+.5), 50);
     ctx.drawImage(coin, 50*(i+.5), 50);
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="700" height="70">
            <!-- Insert fallback content here -->
        </canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Где `coin.png` [image: введите сюда описание изображения] это картинка `16x16`, и её надо центрировать по середине, т.е чтобы в каждом квадрате была эта картинка по середине прямо на букве `H`, пробовал делать `ctx.textAlign = 'center';` но к картинке он не применяется.

P.s Ещё хотел бы спросить почему если нажать `Ctrl+F5` картинки не вырисовываются, но если просто обновлять то все норм

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понимаю надо дождаться когда загрузиться картинка. И только после этого её отрисовывать. То есть придется вынести эту отрисовку из первого цикла.

Также отрисовка по центру картинки вполне подвергается общим принципам:

```
кординатаВнутреннейКартинкиПоX = ШиринаОберткиПоX / 2 - ширинаКартинки / 2;
```

т.к. координаты начинаются с левого верхнего угла, то в координате `ШиринаОберткиПоX / 2` будет левая граница картинки. А чтоб она была по центру - надо её сместить влево. На сколько? Правильно - также наполовину.

зная это, получается:

```
 ctx.drawImage(coin, 70 * (i + .5) - (coin.width / 2), 5);
```

Итог:

```js
function getRandomInt() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (255 - 0)) + 0;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var coin = new Image();
  var rectCount = 10;
  coin.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mnyl3.png';

  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  for (var i = 0; i < rectCount; i++) {
    var coordinates = 70 * i;
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + getRandomInt() + ", " + getRandomInt() + ", " + getRandomInt() + ")";
    ctx.fillRect(coordinates, 0, 70, 70);
    ctx.font = "bold 30px Verdana,sans-serif";
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.strokeText("Н", 70 * (i + .5), 50);
  }

  coin.onload = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < rectCount; i++) {
      ctx.drawImage(coin, 70 * (i + .5) - (coin.width / 2), 5);
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="700" height="70">
  <!-- Insert fallback content here -->
</canvas>
```